# fb:share shown bad in IE, text goes over button

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

Somehow my fb:like widget looks bad in IE8, but ok in Firefox and Chrome. Even the text is different. How could I affect somehow the rendering of the widget?

[image]

Comment: Does the like button at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ look different for you in IE8?

Comment: No. Not exactly the same in IE than in real browsers, but basically ok.

Comment: If I show you a picture of the fix, would you be happy with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me:

> Does the like button at
>   developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like look different for
>   you in IE8?

You:

> No. Not exactly the same in IE than in real browsers, but basically ok.

Since your IE 8 works on the plugin page, then there's something going on in your HTML that is interfering with the plugin.

Your best best is to strip the page down to bare essentials until the button renders correctly in IE8, just as it does on the documentation page.

Then slowly start adding in content until it breaks.  Then you know what caused it and it will be a lot easier to fix it.